# Set pointer to array of structs equal to array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a struct `foo_t` that, within it, has a pointer to an array of struct, `bar_t`. I also have a struct `spam_t` that, with in, has an array of struct `bar_t`. My goal is to set the pointer to the array of `bar_t` in `foo_t` to the array of `bar_t` in `spam_t`.

The following program attempts to do this. My expectation then, is that if I change, for example, `spam->bar[2].var2`, I should see the new value reflected in `foo.bar[2]->var2`. However, I don't see this happening. The only instance where changes to `spam->bar` appear in `foo.bar` is if I change element `[0]`. What's going on here? How can I properly point `foo.bar` to the same array as `spam->bar`?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    uint16_t var1;
    uint16_t var2;
} bar_t ;

typedef struct {
    bar_t    (* bar)[3];
    uint8_t  spare;
} foo_t;

typedef struct {
    bar_t    bar[3];
} spam_t;


void printVar(foo_t foo, spam_t * spam)
{
    printf("foo.bar[0]->var1:  %d\n",   foo.bar[0]->var1);
    printf("foo.bar[1]->var1:  %d\n",   foo.bar[1]->var1);
    printf("foo.bar[2]->var1:  %d\n",   foo.bar[2]->var1);

    printf("spam->bar[0].var1: %d\n",   spam->bar[0].var1);
    printf("spam->bar[1].var1: %d\n",   spam->bar[1].var1);
    printf("spam->bar[2].var1: %d\n\n", spam->bar[2].var1);

    printf("foo.bar[0]->var2:  %d\n",   foo.bar[0]->var2);
    printf("foo.bar[1]->var2:  %d\n",   foo.bar[1]->var2);
    printf("foo.bar[2]->var2:  %d\n",   foo.bar[2]->var2);

    printf("spam->bar[0].var2: %d\n",   spam->bar[0].var2);
    printf("spam->bar[1].var2: %d\n",   spam->bar[1].var2);
    printf("spam->bar[2].var2: %d\n\n", spam->bar[2].var2);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("Start...\n");

    foo_t    foo;
    spam_t * spam = (spam_t *)malloc(sizeof(spam_t));

    memset(&foo, 0, sizeof(foo_t));
    memset(spam, 0, sizeof(spam_t));

    foo.bar = &(spam->bar);

    printVar(foo, spam);

    spam->bar[0].var1 = 1;
    spam->bar[1].var1 = 1;
    spam->bar[2].var1 = 0;

    spam->bar[0].var2 = 2;
    spam->bar[1].var2 = 1;
    spam->bar[2].var2 = 0;

    //foo.bar[2]->var2 = 3;

    printVar(foo, spam);

    free(spam);

    printf("Done...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly assign the address of the array to the pointer, but I think the way you access your elements is incorrect.

You should change

```
foo.bar[0]->var1
```

to

```
(*foo.bar)[0].var1
```

`foo.bar[0]->var1` is equivalent to `(*foo.bar[0]).var1`. But since `foo.bar` is a pointer to an array you want to first dereference the pointer and then apply the array subscription. Therefore you should write `(*foo.bar)[0].var1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `foo.bar` is a pointer to an `bar_t` array of size 3. So when you use foo.bar[1] you will be beyond that array.

One possible way to get around this is to use an array of size 1:

```
typedef struct {
    bar_t    (* bar)[1];
    uint8_t  spare;
} foo_t;
```

This will trigger a warning for incompatible pointer type, which it should. But it does work the way you want.

But of course, you would want to rewrite it in a more proper way, but this at least demonstrate that the problem is the step size in the array.